# Cannot read property 'large' of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a graphql request. It works fine, but if the poster is missing I got errors.
I tried to fix like this:

```
<div className="movie__hero">
    <img
       src={ movie.poster.large == null ? "poster" : movie.poster.large }
       alt="Poster"
       className="movie__img"
     />
 </div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAulO.png)

Any ideas to fix the issue?

Comment: "if the poster is missing, I [get] errors". So if movie.poster is null, then you can't get the property ".large". So your ternary should be on whether movie.poster is null, not if movie.poster.large is null

Answer (score 0):

The error isn't telling you that `large` is `null`, it's telling you that `poster` is `null`:

```
src={ movie.poster == null ? "poster" : movie.poster.large }
```

Comment: Thank you! This solved the problem.